# Efficient methods to compute PCA for an incrementally growing matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, data-mining

I am wondering if there exists an efficient method to compute PCA. I am drafting the question into a presudo code:

```
matrix = []
pca = [] * 9999999
for i in range (0, 9999999):
    matrix = add_one_new_row(matrix)
    pca[i].append(do_pca(matrix))
```

I will need to calculate `PCA` each time for an incrementally growing matrix. While the above method would give me the `PCA` each time, I am just wondering if there exists a more efficient algorithm on this, since when calculating `PCA` for `nth` time, I have all the previously calculated `PCA` already.

Comment: how many components are there in the PCA?

Comment: You might want to look into http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_incremental_pca.html

Comment: I'm afraid not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PCA components are eigenvectors of $X^TX$. Adding a row to $X$ corresponds to a rank 1 update of $X^TX$:
$$\begin{pmatrix}X \\ v^T\end{pmatrix}^T \begin{pmatrix}X \\ v^T\end{pmatrix} = X^TX + vv^T.$$
You can use the [Bunch–Nielsen–Sorensen formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunch%E2%80%93Nielsen%E2%80%93Sorensen_formula) to get the eigenvalues of $X^TX + vv^T$ based on the eigenvalues of $X^TX$. To apply the formula, you first have to perform a linear transformation to $X^TX$ to make it diagonal (full details in [this publication](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01396012)), which may null the speed gains. An alternative formula is presented in [this paper](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/S089547989223924X).

Comment: Aren't the all the PCA components eigenvectors of $X^TX$? Thus, PCA analysis has already effectively diagonlized $X^TX$.

Comment: @Acccumulation if he is interested in all components, you are right